# React Router Link dont updated page data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I have this react + redux app

I have 1 Movie component with some movie data displayed on it which are fetched from API.

So at the bottom, i decided to add a Similar movies section with a couple of  components to navigate to the new movie pages.

```
<div className="similar_movieS_container">
    { this.props.thisMovieIdDataSIMILAR.slice(0,4).map((movie,index)=>{
         return(

            <Link to={"/movie/"+movie.id} key={index}>

               <div className="similar_movie_container">
                 <div className="similar_movie_img_holder">
                   <img src={"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/"+movie.poster_path} className="similar_movie_img" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Link>
                )
            })
          }
 </div>
```

Now when I'm at a root route for instance `/toprated` and i click on a `<Link to={"/movie/"+movie.id} key={index}>` i  get  navigated to the particular route (e.g. `/movie/234525` ) and everything works fine , but if I'm in a `/movies/{some move ID }` route and i click on some `<Link to={"/movie/"+movie.id} key={index}>` The route in the URL bar gets updated, but the page stays still, meaning nothing changes if I reload the page with the new route the new movieID data is displayed...

So how can  i make a navigation  to a  new `/movie/{movieID}` FOMR a `/movie/{movieID}` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are just within same route.

There are few ways to work around this. I bet you are rendering routes like this.

```
<Route path="/movie/:id" component={Movie} />
```

Try like this.

```
<Route path="/movie/:id" component={() => <Movie />} />
```

Another solution would be to use `componentWillReceiveProps` instead of `componentWillMount`.

Comment: `component={() => <Movie />}` did not solved the problem , and how can i use  `componentWillReceiveProps` towork it out ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the component of page *movie* was mounted, so the render method of this component will not be mounted again or updated, so you need to fire a code to change the state, and consequently re-rendering the page content, for this you can implement the componentDidUpdate method which is fired for every props modification.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Basically you implement the same code above inside